Unable to install Torch using pip
I using Windows
I installed Python 3.13
I am trying to pip install torch
However, when attempting to do so, I encounter this error.
F:\Kit>pip install torch
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

What is the issue and how can it be resolved?

The pytorch documentation says pytorch on windows only supports python 3.8-3.11 - you'll need to downgrade to python 3.11 to install

It is stated in the docs that:

PyTorch on Windows only supports Python 3.8-3.11.

However on PyPi, The stable release of torch (i.e. version 2.4.1)  supports Python 3.8 - 3.12. There are wheels for Python 3.12 Windows as can be seen here.
However, there is no support yet for Python 3.13. To use this package, downgrade to a supported version perhaps Python 3.12.


Install 3.11 version: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3110/
Create env: python3.11 -m venv ~/.venv/3.11
Activate: ~/.venv/3.11/bin/activate
Check: python --version

